# 2D DFT through FFTW

Tags: c, fft, fftw

I'm trying to move my 2D dft to FFTW but I'm facing problems.

In my old code I performed a 1D C2C along z and then 1D C2R along x direction.
Now I'm trying to use the 2D C2R from FFTW but I miss something and the output are different..

This is what I've tried:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <fftw3-mpi.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 4

int main (int argv, char **argc)
{
int nz=N*2+1, nx=N+1;
int nxd=8, nzd=12;
int rank, size;
double *real;   
fftw_complex *complx, *data;
double t1, t2;
fftw_plan plan;
ptrdiff_t alloc_local, local_n0, local_0_start, alloc_local_data, local_n0_data, local_0_start_data;

MPI_Init (&argv, &argc);
fftw_mpi_init ();

MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

alloc_local_data = fftw_mpi_local_size_2d (nz, nx, 
                                      MPI_COMM_WORLD, 
                                      &local_n0_data,  
                                      &local_0_start_data);
alloc_local = fftw_mpi_local_size_2d (nzd, nxd, 
                                      MPI_COMM_WORLD, 
                                      &local_n0,  
                                      &local_0_start);
data = fftw_alloc_complex(alloc_local);
real = (double*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(double) * 2*alloc_local);
complx = fftw_alloc_complex(alloc_local);

plan = fftw_mpi_plan_dft_c2r_2d (nzd,(nxd-1)*2, complx, real, 
                             MPI_COMM_WORLD, 
                                 FFTW_MEASURE);
/*plan_f = fftw_mpi_plan_dft_r2c_2d (nzd, nxd, complx, real,
                             MPI_COMM_WORLD, 
                                 FFTW_MEASURE);*/
// realitialize realput with some numbers   
for (int i = 0; i < local_n0_data; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < nz; k++) {
        data[k+i*nz][0] = 2*(k+(i+local_0_start_data)*(nz));
        data[k+i*nz][1] = 2*(k+(i+local_0_start_data)*(nz))+1;
    //  printf("[%d]complex[%d]= %f+I*%f\n",rank,k+i*(nz), data[k+i*(nz)][0], data[k+i*(nz)][1]  );
    }
    //printf("-----------------\n");
}

/*Move data inside nxd=8xnzd=12 array*/
for(int i=0; i < 5; i++){
    for(int k=0; k < 5; k++) {
        complx[i*nzd+k][0]=data[(k+nz/2)+i*nz][0];
        complx[i*nzd+k][1]=data[(k+nz/2)+i*nz][1];
        //printf("[%d]complex[%d]= %f+I*%f\n",rank,k+i*(nzd), complx[k+i*(nzd)][0], complx[k+i*(nzd)][1]  );
    }   
}
for(int i=0; i < 5; i++){
    for(int k=5; k < 8; k++) {
        complx[i*nzd+k][0]=0;
        complx[i*nzd+k][1]=0;
        //printf("[%d]complex[%d]= %f+I*%f\n",rank,k+i*(nzd), complx[k+i*(nzd)][0], complx[k+i*(nzd)][1]  );
    }   
}
for(int i=0; i < 5; i++){
    for(int k=8; k < nzd; k++) {
        complx[i*nzd+k][0]=data[(k-nz+1)+i*nz][0];
        complx[i*nzd+k][1]=data[(k-nz+1)+i*nz][1];
        //printf("[%d]complex[%d]= %f+I*%f\n",rank,k+i*(nzd), complx[k+i*(nzd)][0], complx[k+i*(nzd)][1]  );
    }   
}
for(int i=5; i < nxd;i++){
    for(int k=0; k<nzd;k++){
        complx[i*nzd+k][0]=0;
        complx[i*nzd+k][1]=0;
    }
}
/*for(int i=0;i<nxd;i++){
    for(int k=0; k< nzd;k++){
        printf("complx[%d]=%f+I*%f\n",i*nzd+k,complx[i*nzd+k][0],complx[i*nzd+k][1]);
    }
    printf("----------------\n");
}*/

/*transform*/
fftw_execute(plan);

for(int i=0;i<2*(nxd-1);i++){
    for(int k=0; k< nzd;k++){
        printf("real[%d]=%f\n",i*nzd+k,real[i*nzd+k]);
    }
    printf("----------------\n");
}

// Clean up and get complx
//free(real);   free(complx);   fftw_free(data);
fftw_destroy_plan (plan);
MPI_Finalize ();
return 0;
}
```

As you can see I'm using FFTW with MPI support, but for the moment I'm working in single core, so don't worry about possibile array bound errors.

The working array is 8x12 (nx,nz) which is filled with values that comes from the array data, which is 5x9.

I've followed a couples of examples from the manual, [here](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/2d-MPI-example.html#g_t2d-MPI-example) and [here](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Multi_002ddimensional-MPI-DFTs-of-Real-Data.html)

Any advice will be welcomed!

Comment: What is the output now and what should the output be? I'm not familiar with the mpi interface of fftw, but others who are will want to know what the goal is here :) You might want to try a 2D DFT through the regular fftw library, as multi-threading for such a small array seems a bit overkill.